# Android: calling Activities explicitly using Intent Url scheme

Tags: android, android-intent, url-scheme

im trying to understand how `Intent URL's` working in android . i know that i can make implicit call to activities which has a intent-filter set in `AndroidManifest` file . but as far I've read we can call application Activities which has no `intent-filter` set in `AndroidManifest` . i tried some cases but i couldn't make it happen . i wrote a simple application with some Activities (no `intent-filter`) but i couldn't run them using Intent URL . and i couldn't find any useful example on `explicit intent url's` in the internet (and `stackoverflow`) .

so i'd be thankful if anyone could provide a simple exmple for `explicit Activity calls using intent url's` or a brief explanation .

Regards,
Mohammad

Comment: By default, an activity without an `<intent-filter>` is not exported, and so it cannot be started by other apps. So, I suggest that you provide a [mcve] demonstrating what you tried and explain, in detail, what "i couldn't run them using Intent URL" means.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late for this answer, But for future reference, I'm thinking by **Intent Url** you mean the **Uri** of your intent.

There is an easy to find the `Uri` format of any intent (explicit or implicit) just by declaring an `Intent` object with those parameters in java and then calling the `toUri` method which gives you the String format of that intent. You can then use it in your web page to communicate with your app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
String intentUri = intent.toUri(0);
```